# How do you stop cherrypy custom tools used as decorators being applied to static files?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cherrypy

I'm trying to develop an app for Google App Engine using Cherrypy.

I'm using a custom tool to apply templates with.  Part of the output is a html css stylesheet declaration.  I can get cherrypy to find and load the css file no problem, the problem is the template gets applied to the css output.

Here's my code I'm using

```
import cherrypy
from lib.tools.template import HamlTool

engine = cherrypy.engine

from lib.plugin.template import MakoTemplatePlugin
engine.mako = MakoTemplatePlugin(engine, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'))
engine.mako.subscribe()

class Root(object):
  exposed = True

  @tools.encode()
  @tools.template(template='index.haml')
  def GET(self):
    return 'Hello I like CherryPy!'

cherrypy.tools.template = HamlTool()

conf = {
  '/': {
    'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
  },
  '/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css' : {
    'tools.staticfile.on': True,
    'tools.staticfile.filename' : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')
  }
}

root = Root()

app = cherrypy.tree.mount(root, '/', config=conf)
run_wsgi_app(app)
```

This is the HamlTool code

```
import cherrypy
import haml
import mako.lookup

class HamlTool(cherrypy.Tool):
  def __init__(self):
    cherrypy.Tool.__init__(self, 'before_finalize',
                           self._render,
                           priority=0)


  def _render(self, template=None):
    if cherrypy.response.status > 399:
        return

    # retrieve the data returned by the handler
    data = {'data':''.join(cherrypy.response.body), 'title': 'Hello there'} or {}

    try:
      template = cherrypy.engine.publish("lookup-template", template).pop()
    except:
      template = None
    print
    print 'template: ', template

    if template:
        # dump the template using the dictionary
        cherrypy.response.body = str(template.render(**data))
```

And the MakoTemplatePlugin code

```
from cherrypy.process import plugins
import mako.lookup
import haml

class MakoTemplatePlugin(plugins.SimplePlugin):
  def __init__(self, engine, template_dir='templates'):
    super(MakoTemplatePlugin, self).__init__(engine)
    self.template_dir = template_dir
    print 'MakoTemplatePlugin: init', self.template_dir
    self.lookup = mako.lookup.TemplateLookup(
                        directories=self.template_dir,
                        preprocessor=haml.preprocessor
                  )
    self.bus.subscribe('lookup-template', self.get_template)

  def start(self):
    print 'MakoTemplatePlugin: start', self.template_dir
    self.lookup = mako.lookup.TemplateLookup(
                        directories=self.template_dir,
                        preprocessor=haml.preprocessor
                  )
    self.bus.subscribe('lookup-template', self.get_template)



  def stop(self):
    self.bus.unsubscribe('lookup-template', self.get_template)
    self.lookup = None



  def get_template(self, name):
    print 'MakoTemplatePlugin: lookup template', name, self.template_dir
    return self.lookup.get_template(name)
```

The base template

```
!!! 5

%html(lang="en")
  %head
    %title= title
    %meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    %link(href="/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
  %body
    .container-fluid=self.body()
    %script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js")
    %script(src="/assets/js/bootstrap-responsive.min.js")
```

The actual template which inherits from base

```
<%inherit file="base.haml"/>

.row-fluid
  .span12-fluid=data
```

The output from the root is fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello there</title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
        <link href="/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12-fluid">Hello I like CherryPy!</div>
</div>
</div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-responsive.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but when you have a look at the output from the css you get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello there</title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
        <link href="/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12-fluid">/*!
 * Bootstrap Responsive v2.3.1
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat.
 */.clearfix{*zoom:1}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;line-height:0;content:""}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.hide-text{font:0/0 a;color:transparent;text-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;border:0}.input-block-level{display:block;width:100%;min-height:30px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}.hidden{display:none;visibility:hidden}.visible-phone{display:none!important}.visible-tablet{display:none!important}.hidden-desktop{display:none!important}.visible-desktop{display:inherit!important}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:979px){.hidden-desktop{display:inherit!important}.visible-desktop{display:none!important}.visible-tablet{display:inherit!important}.hidden-tablet{display:none!important}}@media(max-width:767px){.hidden-desktop{display:inherit!important}.visible-desktop{display:none!important}.visible-phone{display:inherit!important}.hidden-phone{display:none!important}}.visible-print{display:none!important}@media print{.visible-print{display:inherit!important}.hidden-print{display:none!important}}@media(min-width:1200px){.row{margin-left:-30px;*zoom:1}.row:before,.row:after{display:table;line-height:0;content:""}.row:after{clear:both}[class*="span"]{float:left;min-height:1px;margin-left:30px}.container,.navbar-static-top .container,.navbar-fixed-top .container,.navbar-fixed-bottom .container{width:1170px}.span12{width:1170px}.span11{width:1070px}.span10{width:970px}.span9{width:870px}.span8{width:770px}.span7{width:670px}.span6{width:570px}.span5{width:470px}.span4{width:370px}.span3{width:270px}.span2{width:170px}.span1{width:70px}.offset12{margin-left:1230px}.offset11{margin-left:1130px}.offset10{margin-left:1030px}.offset9{margin-left:930px}.offset8{margin-left:830px}.offset7{margin-left:730px}.offset6{margin-left:630px}.offset5{margin-left:530px}.offset4{margin-left:430px}.offset3{margin-left:330px}.offset2{margin-left:230px}.offset1{margin-left:130px}.row-fluid{width:100%;*zoom:1}.row-fluid:before,.row-fluid:after{display:table;line-height:0;content:""}.row-fluid:after{clear:both}.row-fluid [class*="span"]{display:block;float:left;width:100%;min-height:30px;margin-left:2.564102564102564%;*margin-left:2.5109110747408616%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child{margin-left:0}.row-fluid .controls-row [class*="span"]+[class*="span"]{margin-left:2.564102564102564%}.row-fluid .span12{width:100%;*width:99.94680851063829%}.row-fluid .span11{width:91.45299145299145%;*width:91.39979996362975%}.row-fluid .span10{width:82.90598290598291%;*width:82.8527914166212%}.row-fluid .span9{width:74.35897435897436%;*width:74.30578286961266%}.row-fluid .span8{width:65.81196581196582%;*width:65.75877432260411%}.row-fluid .span7{width:57.26495726495726%;*width:57.21176577559556%}.row-fluid .span6{width:48.717948717948715%;*width:48.664757228587014%}.row-fluid .span5{width:40.17094017094017%;*width:40.11774868157847%}.row-fluid .span4{width:31.623931623931625%;*width:31.570740134569924%}.row-fluid .span3{width:23.076923076923077%;*width:23.023731587561375%}.row-fluid .span2{width:14.52991452991453%;*width:14.476723040552828%}.row-fluid .span1{width:5.982905982905983%;*width:5.929714493544281%}.row-fluid .offset12{margin-left:105.12820512820512%;*margin-left:105.02182214948171%}.row-fluid .offset12:first-child{margin-left:102.56410256410257%;*margin-left:102.45771958537915%}.row-fluid .offset11{margin-left:96.58119658119658%;*margin-left:96.47481360247316%}.row-fluid .offset11:first-child{margin-left:94.01709401709402%;*margin-left:93.91071103837061%}.row-fluid .offset10{margin-left:88.03418803418803%;*margin-left:87.92780505546462%}.row-fluid .offset10:first-child{margin-left:85.47008547008548%;*margin-left:85.36370249136206%}.row-fluid .offset9{margin-left:79.48717948717949%;*margin-left:79.38079650845607%}.row-fluid .offset9:first-child{margin-left:76.92307692307693%;*margin-left:76.81669394435352%}.row-fluid .offset8{margin-left:70.94017094017094%;*margin-left:70.83378796144753%}.row-fluid .offset8:first-child{margin-left:68.37606837606839%;*margin-left:68.26968539734497%}.row-fluid .offset7{margin-left:62.393162393162385%;*margin-left:62.28677941443899%}.row-fluid .offset7:first-child{margin-left:59.82905982905982%;*margin-left:59.72267685033642%}.row-fluid .offset6{margin-left:53.84615384615384%;*margin-left:53.739770867430444%}.row-fluid .offset6:first-child{margin-left:51.28205128205128%;*margin-left:51.175668303327875%}.row-fluid .offset5{margin-left:45.299145299145295%;*margin-left:45.1927623204219%}.row-fluid .offset5:first-child{margin-left:42.73504273504273%;*margin-left:42.62865975631933%}.row-fluid .offset4{margin-left:36.75213675213675%;*margin-left:36.645753773413354%}.row-fluid .offset4:first-child{margin-left:34.18803418803419%;*margin-left:34.081651209310785%}.row-fluid .offset3{margin-left:28.205128205128204%;*margin-left:28.0987452264048%}.row-fluid .offset3:first-child{margin-left:25.641025641025642%;*margin-left:25.53464266230224%}.row-fluid .offset2{margin-left:19.65811965811966%;*margin-left:19.551736679396257%}.row-fluid .offset2:first-child{margin-left:17.094017094017094%;*margin-left:16.98763411529369%}.row-fluid .offset1{margin-left:11.11111111111111%;*margin-left:11.004728132387708%}.row-fluid .offset1:first-child{margin-left:8.547008547008547%;*margin-left:8.440625568285142%}input,textarea,.uneditable-input{margin-left:0}.controls-row [class*="span"]+[class*="span"]{margin-left:30px}input.span12,textarea.span12,.uneditable-input.span12{width:1156px}input.span11,textarea.span11,.uneditable-input.span11{width:1056px}input.span10,textarea.span10,.uneditable-input.span10{width:956px}input.span9,textarea.span9,.uneditable-input.span9{width:856px}input.span8,textarea.span8,.uneditable-input.span8{width:756px}input.span7,textarea.span7,.uneditable-input.span7{width:656px}input.span6,textarea.span6,.uneditable-input.span6{width:556px}input.span5,textarea.span5,.uneditable-input.span5{width:456px}input.span4,textarea.span4,.uneditable-input.span4{width:356px}input.span3,textarea.span3,.uneditable-input.span3{width:256px}input.span2,textarea.span2,.uneditable-input.span2{width:156px}input.span1,textarea.span1,.uneditable-input.span1{width:56px}.thumbnails{margin-left:-30px}.thumbnails>li{margin-left:30px}.row-fluid .thumbnails{margin-left:0}}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:979px){.row{margin-left:-20px;*zoom:1}.row:before,.row:after{display:table;line-height:0;content:""}.row:after{clear:both}[class*="span"]{float:left;min-height:1px;margin-left:20px}.container,.navbar-static-top .container,.navbar-fixed-top .container,.navbar-fixed-bottom .container{width:724px}.span12{width:724px}.span11{width:662px}.span10{width:600px}.span9{width:538px}.span8{width:476px}.span7{width:414px}.span6{width:352px}.span5{width:290px}.span4{width:228px}.span3{width:166px}.span2{width:104px}.span1{width:42px}.offset12{margin-left:764px}.offset11{margin-left:702px}.offset10{margin-left:640px}.offset9{margin-left:578px}.offset8{margin-left:516px}.offset7{margin-left:454px}.offset6{margin-left:392px}.offset5{margin-left:330px}.offset4{margin-left:268px}.offset3{margin-left:206px}.offset2{margin-left:144px}.offset1{margin-left:82px}.row-fluid{width:100%;*zoom:1}.row-fluid:before,.row-fluid:after{display:table;line-height:0;content:""}.row-fluid:after{clear:both}.row-fluid [class*="span"]{display:block;float:left;width:100%;min-height:30px;margin-left:2.7624309392265194%;*margin-left:2.709239449864817%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child{margin-left:0}.row-fluid .controls-row [class*="span"]+[class*="span"]{margin-left:2.7624309392265194%}.row-fluid .span12{width:100%;*width:99.94680851063829%}.row-fluid .span11{width:91.43646408839778%;*width:91.38327259903608%}.row-fluid .span10{width:82.87292817679558%;*width:82.81973668743387%}.row-fluid .span9{width:74.30939226519337%;*width:74.25620077583166%}.row-fluid .span8{width:65.74585635359117%;*width:65.69266486422946%}.row-fluid .span7{width:57.18232044198895%;*width:57.12912895262725%}.row-fluid .span6{width:48.61878453038674%;*width:48.56559304102504%}.row-fluid .span5{width:40.05524861878453%;*width:40.00205712942283%}.row-fluid .span4{width:31.491712707182323%;*width:31.43852121782062%}.row-fluid .span3{width:22.92817679558011%;*width:22.87498530621841%}.row-fluid .span2{width:14.3646408839779%;*width:14.311449394616199%}.row-fluid .span1{width:5.801104972375691%;*width:5.747913483013988%}.row-fluid .offset12{margin-left:105.52486187845304%;*margin-left:105.41847889972962%}.row-fluid .offset12:first-child{margin-left:102.76243093922652%;*margin-left:102.6560479605031%}.row-fluid .offset11{margin-left:96.96132596685082%;*margin-left:96.8549429881274%}.row-fluid .offset11:first-child{margin-left:94.1988950276243%;*margin-left:94.09251204890089%}.row-fluid .offset10{margin-left:88.39779005524862%;*margin-left:88.2914070765252%}.row-fluid .offset10:first-child{margin-left:85.6353591160221%;*margin-left:85.52897613729868%}.row-fluid .offset9{margin-left:79.8342541436464%;*margin-left:79.72787116492299%}.row-fluid .offset9:first-child{margin-left:77.07182320441989%;*margin-left:76.96544022569647%}.row-fluid .offset8{margin-left:71.2707182320442%;*margin-left:71.16433525332079%}.row-fluid .offset8:first-child{margin-left:68.50828729281768%;*margin-left:68.40190431409427%}.row-fluid .offset7{margin-left:62.70718232044199%;*margin-left:62.600799341718584%}.row-fluid .offset7:first-child{margin-left:59.94475138121547%;*margin-left:59.838368402492065%}.row-fluid .offset6{margin-left:54.14364640883978%;*margin-left:54.037263430116376%}.row-fluid .offset6:first-child{margin-left:51.38121546961326%;*margin-left:51.27483249088986%}.row-fluid .offset5{margin-left:45.58011049723757%;*margin-left:45.47372751851417%}.row-fluid .offset5:first-child{margin-left:42.81767955801105%;*margin-left:42.71129657928765%}.row-fluid .offset4{margin-left:37.01657458563536%;*margin-left:36.91019160691196%}.row-fluid .offset4:first-child{margin-left:34.25414364640884%;*margin-left:34.14776066768544%}.row-fluid .offset3{margin-left:28.45303867403315%;*margin-left:28.346655695309746%}.row-fluid .offset3:first-child{margin-left:25.69060773480663%;*margin-left:25.584224756083227%}.row-fluid .offset2{margin-left:19.88950276243094%;*margin-left:19.783119783707537%}.row-fluid .offset2:first-child{margin-left:17.12707182320442%;*margin-left:17.02068884448102%}.row-fluid .offset1{margin-left:11.32596685082873%;*margin-left:11.219583872105325%}.row-fluid .offset1:first-child{margin-left:8.56353591160221%;*margin-left:8.457152932878806%}input,textarea,.uneditable-input{margin-left:0}.controls-row [class*="span"]+[class*="span"]{margin-left:20px}input.span12,textarea.span12,.uneditable-input.span12{width:710px}input.span11,textarea.span11,.uneditable-input.span11{width:648px}input.span10,textarea.span10,.uneditable-input.span10{width:586px}input.span9,textarea.span9,.uneditable-input.span9{width:524px}input.span8,textarea.span8,.uneditable-input.span8{width:462px}input.span7,textarea.span7,.uneditable-input.span7{width:400px}input.span6,textarea.span6,.uneditable-input.span6{width:338px}input.span5,textarea.span5,.uneditable-input.span5{width:276px}input.span4,textarea.span4,.uneditable-input.span4{width:214px}input.span3,textarea.span3,.uneditable-input.span3{width:152px}input.span2,textarea.span2,.uneditable-input.span2{width:90px}input.span1,textarea.span1,.uneditable-input.span1{width:28px}}@media(max-width:767px){body{padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px}.navbar-fixed-top,.navbar-fixed-bottom,.navbar-static-top{margin-right:-20px;margin-left:-20px}.container-fluid{padding:0}.dl-horizontal dt{float:none;width:auto;clear:none;text-align:left}.dl-horizontal dd{margin-left:0}.container{width:auto}.row-fluid{width:100%}.row,.thumbnails{margin-left:0}.thumbnails>li{float:none;margin-left:0}[class*="span"],.uneditable-input[class*="span"],.row-fluid [class*="span"]{display:block;float:none;width:100%;margin-left:0;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.span12,.row-fluid .span12{width:100%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.row-fluid [class*="offset"]:first-child{margin-left:0}.input-large,.input-xlarge,.input-xxlarge,input[class*="span"],select[class*="span"],textarea[class*="span"],.uneditable-input{display:block;width:100%;min-height:30px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.input-prepend input,.input-append input,.input-prepend input[class*="span"],.input-append input[class*="span"]{display:inline-block;width:auto}.controls-row [class*="span"]+[class*="span"]{margin-left:0}.modal{position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;left:20px;width:auto;margin:0}.modal.fade{top:-100px}.modal.fade.in{top:20px}}@media(max-width:480px){.nav-collapse{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}.page-header h1 small{display:block;line-height:20px}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{border:1px solid #ccc}.form-horizontal .control-label{float:none;width:auto;padding-top:0;text-align:left}.form-horizontal .controls{margin-left:0}.form-horizontal .control-list{padding-top:0}.form-horizontal .form-actions{padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px}.media .pull-left,.media .pull-right{display:block;float:none;margin-bottom:10px}.media-object{margin-right:0;margin-left:0}.modal{top:10px;right:10px;left:10px}.modal-header .close{padding:10px;margin:-10px}.carousel-caption{position:static}}@media(max-width:979px){body{padding-top:0}.navbar-fixed-top,.navbar-fixed-bottom{position:static}.navbar-fixed-top{margin-bottom:20px}.navbar-fixed-bottom{margin-top:20px}.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner,.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-inner{padding:5px}.navbar .container{width:auto;padding:0}.navbar .brand{padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;margin:0 0 0 -5px}.nav-collapse{clear:both}.nav-collapse .nav{float:none;margin:0 0 10px}.nav-collapse .nav>li{float:none}.nav-collapse .nav>li>a{margin-bottom:2px}.nav-collapse .nav>.divider-vertical{display:none}.nav-collapse .nav .nav-header{color:#777;text-shadow:none}.nav-collapse .nav>li>a,.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a{padding:9px 15px;font-weight:bold;color:#777;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px}.nav-collapse .btn{padding:4px 10px 4px;font-weight:normal;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px}.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu li+li a{margin-bottom:2px}.nav-collapse .nav>li>a:hover,.nav-collapse .nav>li>a:focus,.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover,.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus{background-color:#f2f2f2}.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav>li>a,.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a{color:#999}.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav>li>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav>li>a:focus,.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover,.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus{background-color:#111}.nav-collapse.in .btn-group{padding:0;margin-top:5px}.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu{position:static;top:auto;left:auto;display:none;float:none;max-width:none;padding:0;margin:0 15px;background-color:transparent;border:0;-webkit-border-radius:0;-moz-border-radius:0;border-radius:0;-webkit-box-shadow:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none}.nav-collapse .open>.dropdown-menu{display:block}.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:before,.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:after{display:none}.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu .divider{display:none}.nav-collapse .nav>li>.dropdown-menu:before,.nav-collapse .nav>li>.dropdown-menu:after{display:none}.nav-collapse .navbar-form,.nav-collapse .navbar-search{float:none;padding:10px 15px;margin:10px 0;border-top:1px solid #f2f2f2;border-bottom:1px solid #f2f2f2;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1)}.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .navbar-form,.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .navbar-search{border-top-color:#111;border-bottom-color:#111}.navbar .nav-collapse .nav.pull-right{float:none;margin-left:0}.nav-collapse,.nav-collapse.collapse{height:0;overflow:hidden}.navbar .btn-navbar{display:block}.navbar-static .navbar-inner{padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px}}@media(min-width:980px){.nav-collapse.collapse{height:auto!important;overflow:visible!important}}
</div>
</div>
</div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-responsive.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What have I done wrong and how do I prevent the tenmplate from being applied to css and javascript files referenced by this page?

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that I already tried disabling the template plugin on the static files by putting

```
'tools.template.on':False
```

in the static files part of the config.  The only way I seem to be able to stop this is to remove the templates decorator all together.  The only problem with that is the template will not be applied and the output will not include the html which includes the desired css import.

Answer (score 0):

In your static sections, simply disable the tool:

tools.template.on: False

Comment: No I tried that already, it doesn't make a difference.  I'll update my question to reflect this.